# How does Windows handle multiple DLLs loaded in memory without position independent code?

Tags: windows, linker, operating-system, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Linux and MacOS leverage the power of Position-Independent Code. There's no such thing on Windows and yet programs can link against shared DLLs normally. I can't seem to find good documentation on this topic, besides a couple of terse articles on the Microsoft website ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/about-dynamic-link-libraries) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking)).
Does Windows just copy the DLL code in memory and adjust function addresses as needed? What if two programs link against the same library? Could the virtual memory mechanism be involved somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows PE (.exe/.dll) files contain relocation data that allows the loader to adjust addresses as required if the code is loaded at an address other than the intended base address.

The relocation table is essentially just a list of offsets within the binary that need to be adjusted, such that e.g. if a .dll with a base address of 0x100000, is instead loaded at 0x300000, each of the addresses included in the relocation table will have (0x300000 - 0x100000) = 0x200000 added to them.

Further details on the format of the relocation data with the PE file, and the structure of such files generally can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10)#pe-file-base-relocations

Comment: Cool, so conceptually it's similar to PIC - an additional layer of abstraction over raw addresses?

Comment: @Ignorant - I'd say they achieve the same end (being able to load code at any address) but in different ways - PIC can inherently be loaded at any address without modification, whereas relocations tell the loader what needs modifying to enable the code to be moved to a different base address. The addresses compiled into the binary are still normal addresses, they just assume that the code is loaded at a particular base address. Relocations therefore only need to be applied if the load address is different to the compiled-in base address.